# Changing the Default browser to debug in an ASP.NET MVC 2 Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I just created my first MVC2 project using the standard template.  I need to be able to change the default browser for my project to test in IE (I use chrome as the default on my OS).

Unfortunately, the `right click on default.aspx` suggestion which worked in MVC1 can't work with these new projects as they don't have that file.

Comment: What do you mean 'you don't have that file'?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I confirmed that my newly created mvc2 proj doesn't have a default.aspx file.  Right clicking on any of the mvc2 view pages doesn't give you the right options.  I wasn't able to add a new item and choose a web forms style aspx page (not avail in the selection boxes).  But, I could add a static HTML page and that DOES have the context menu option I need.

So, I'm up and running now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to click on the `Default.aspx` (this is a MVC2 project) file and choose any of the browsers installed in my system. Are you sure it's not working for you?

[image: MVC2 Default Browser]

If for some reason you don't have `Default.aspx` you can also add one, can you not?

If not, you can add a static `.html` page and use that as well.

Comment: Still not sure why the mvc2 proj I created didn't have a default.aspx file.  Using the project wizard I couldn't add a web forms style aspx page (which gives you the context action needed).  However, I could add a static HTML page to my project and using that follow the advice to right click on that to change browser settings. 

Thanks!